# What is the order that foreach in PHP should respect when iterating over an array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I know that PHP array is not an array, it is actually an ordered hashmap, but it still does not make sense to me why if I run this code:

```
<?php

$teste = [];
$teste[2] = 'Test 2';
$teste[1] = 'Test 1';
$teste[3] = 'Test 3';

foreach ($teste as $t) {
    echo $t;
}
```

It prints the following:

```
Test 2
Test 1
Test 3
```

The result does not make sense to me, shouldn't it be ordered like:

```
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
```

Comment: The items are ordered in the order as they are added to the array. But you can sort the array by it's key and you will have expected order :)

Comment: @DamianDziaduch Yeah, that's what I realized too, what's strange is that PHP documentation mentions it as ordered, shouldn't the documentation mention that it's just a Map then?

Comment: Interesting! In the book Learning PHP 7, Antonio Lopez, there this explanation about arrays: "In PHP, we do not have lists and maps; we have arrays. An array is a data structure that implements both a list and a map." Then, at the moment that you sets your own index to your array, you must be saying the order is not important to you. So it is treated like a key, not a index. Well, it's just a clue. I hope to see more details.

Answer (score 1):

[All arrays in PHP are actually ordered maps](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Thus, the order in which key-value pairs are encountered in the map will depend primarily on the order in which they were added to the map. Arrays with a `0..n-1` index sequence in strict increasing order are simply a special case. You can test this by doing the following:

```php
$my_arr = array();
$my_arr[3] = 'd';
$my_arr[1] = 'b';
$my_arr[2] = 'c';
$my_arr[0] = 'a';

// #1
echo json_encode($my_arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . "\n";

// #2
ksort($my_arr);
echo json_encode($my_arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output for #1:

```
{
    "3": "d",
    "1": "b",
    "2": "c",
    "0": "a"
}
```

Output for #2:

```
[
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d"
]
```

Note that the only difference between the two versions of `$my_arr` is the order of the keys. Out of order, the array is encoded as an object, but in order the array is encoded as a simple array.

Please review the linked section of the documentation for more information about PHP's arrays. This is already a well-documented feature of the language. If you desire a strict increasing sort order for your keys, use `ksort()` as shown in the example above.

Comment: So my only safe bet is always ordering an array before I do a foreach? PHP is such a mess, in every other language the map is actually ordered.

Comment: @gtbono It's really not a mess at all. This is a feature, not a bug. If you're assigning keys to an uninitialized array, then you're at fault for not initializing it correctly. How is PHP supposed to know what your intent is? If you must have the keys in a specific order, then either a) define them in the order you want them to appear, or b) perform a sort after defining them. You could, for instance, initialize the array as `[ 1 => null, 2 => null, 3 => null ]` or `array_fill_keys(array(1, 2, 3), null)` and then perform the assignment after. You have multiple options available to you.

Comment: To expand on this: the keys not being re-sorted on a new key being added has additional benefits. First, there is a performance impact for sorting on each insert. With `n` keys and an `O(n log n)` sort algorithm, this gives us `O(n*n log n)`. This is an undesirable performance hit. Even if we simply insert into an array, we get `O(n*n)`. If instead we only sort once after all inserts, our sort runs in `O(n log n)` time, which is better than both sort-on-insert options. Maintaining insertion order also provides functionality that sort-on-insert would wipe out completely.

Comment: In all cases, for those who don't care about the insertion order, the performance impact of a sort will never enter into the equation. Their inserts will retain an `O(1)` running time complexity. In most cases the order of a map doesn't matter, so discarding this additional sort complexity provides a performance benefit to most use cases out of the box. For those special edge cases that require the sorting behavior, `ksort()` exists to fill the gap. For those that don't want to remember to call `ksort()`, they can wrap assignment in a function that invokes `ksort()` after the assignment.